# System clock app breaks AlarmManager on Alcatel One Touch Idol 2 S and Alcatel One Touch Pop S3 (and others?)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

We've been made aware of a strange issue concerning mostly some Alcatel devices. We've somewhat luckily managed to find a solution/workaround only through talking to users.

The problem is that we use AlarmManager to set alarms both one-off and repeating to trigger some key actions in our app. The alarms work fine after first install and for some time after. But (according to the users) after a few days or a week we stop getting any of the alarms.

Now the surprising workaround is to turn off all alarms in the system clock app. It was suggested by a user who disabled her alarm because of winter break at school and the app started to work normally and broke again after going back to school. It seemed unbelievable at first, but we've confirmed this with multiple users.

At first we thought the problem is only on one specific Alcatel model, but after suggesting the workaround to other users with similar problems it seems to occur on more phones and not only Alcatels:

- Alcatel One Touch Idol 2 mini S,
- Alcatel One Touch Pop S3,
- Pentagram Monster P430-1.

At this point we wouldn't be surprised if there was more.

Has anybody encountered this issue and can offer any more insight?
Do you have any ideas about how to try to locate the source of the problem?
And it's a long shot, but I guess worth a try: does anybody maybe know the actual cause of this strange behaviour?

Comment: Have you gotten your hands on any of this hardware to directly reproduce the phenomenon?

Comment: @CommonsWare Unfortunately not yet. If you'd have any suggestions on what specifically could I look for, then I'd possibly try harder to get one, because that puzzle really bugs me.

Comment: Probably would make sense to show how you are scheduling your alarms. Because there is batching behavior that may impact this. If they did an "optimization" this may be the result of that.